# Golang's SQL package Rows.Scan not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, analytics

I was building a simple privacy friendly analytics service and I wrote SQL that when queried against database (with GUI Client) works like a charm but when rows are queried from golang using `github.com/jmoiron/sqlx` package or inbuild `sql` package it does returns rows but it doesn't scan any of the values from the result.

I'm loading queries through `github.com/qustavo/dotsql` and it loads it properly I checked it by printing it.

Golang structs

```golang
// ReportFilter is used to filter data for reports
type ReportFilter struct {
    Event     string    `db:"event"`
    Domain    string    `db:"domain"`
    StartDate time.Time `db:"start_date"`
    EndDate   time.Time `db:"end_date"`
}

// CoreAnalysis is core analysis of a event.
type CoreAnalysis struct {
    TotalVisitors    string `db:"total_visitors"`
    UniqueVisitors   string `db:"unique_visitors"`
    AverageTimeSpend string `db:"avg_time_spent"`
    AverageScroll    string `db:"avg_scrolled_percentage"`
    Date             string `db:"date"`
}
```

Golang Code

```golang
    CompleteAnalysis := []CoreAnalysis{}

    query, err := db.Queries.Raw("core-event-analysis")

    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to load core-event-analysis query.")
    }

    rows, rerr := db.DB.Query(query, filter.Domain, filter.Event, filter.StartDate, filter.EndDate)
    if rerr != nil {
        panic(rerr)
    }
    fmt.Printf("rows: %v\n", CompleteAnalysis)

    for rows.Next() {

        analysis := CoreAnalysis{}
        if err := rows.Scan(&analysis.TotalVisitors, &analysis.UniqueVisitors, &analysis.AverageScroll, &analysis.AverageTimeSpend, &analysis.Date); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        CompleteAnalysis = append(CompleteAnalysis, analysis)

        fmt.Printf("CompleteAnalysis: %v\n", CompleteAnalysis)
    }

    return CompleteAnalysis
```

SQL: I'm using postgres.

```sql
    SELECT 
            COUNT(visitor_id) AS total_visitors, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT(visitor_id))  AS unique_visitors,
            ROUND(AVG(duration)::numeric,2) AS avg_time_spent,
            ROUND(AVG(scrolled_percentage)::numeric,2) AS avg_scrolled_percentage,
            time::date as date
    FROM "events"
    WHERE domain = $1 AND event =$2 AND time >=$3::date AND time < ($4::date + '1 day'::interval)
    GROUP BY date;
```

**Note**: data loads in rows as it can be seen by printing it, when I printed it it had:

```sh
    rows: &{0xc000200120 0x11a2800 0xc0002a4140 <nil> <nil> {{0 0} 0 0 0 0} false <nil> []}
    CompleteAnalysis: []
```

Can anyone tell be what's wrong with this. Also is there any more efficient way to run `DISTINCT` operation on database ?

Edit: Complete code can be accessed here: https://github.com/KetanIP/analytics-backend

Comment: Did you try running exactly the same query against the same DB via `psql`?

Comment: @bereal the query is returning result in rows but I think the problem is in rows.Scan.

Comment: `rows` is probably empty, note that `Query` does not return `sql.ErrNoRows` like the `QueryRow` does, instead `Query` returns a valid `*sql.Rows` object whose method `Next()` will always return `false` if no rows were found, hence your code will never go through the loop's iteration block and therefore will not invoke `rows.Scan`. Can you actually confirm that the `for rows.Next() {` loop iterates at least once? If not, then this is not a `Scan` issue.

Comment: I Printed rows ` rows: &{0xc000200120 0x11a2800 0xc0002a4140 <nil> <nil> {{0 0} 0 0 0 0} false <nil> []}` it came out to be this I think there is nothing wrong with the query as when it is ran on Beekeeper Studio ( like MSQL workbench ) it works fine and returns appropriate response.

Comment: Again, `Query` returns a valid `*sql.Rows` object even if no rows matched the query. Printing that object tells you nothing about whether your query matched or not.

Comment: Instead add `fmt.Println("found a row!")` statement inside the loop, run the code. Do you see at least one `found a row!` in stdout? If not, you've got no match for your query.

Comment: But when I run query on something like Beekeeper studio it returns rows of data. how does that work ?

Comment: More than one possible cause: 1. The query you're executing in Go is actually not the same as the one you executed in the other environment. 2. You're not connected to the same database. 3. You're not using the same schema. 4. Your Go connection does not have the same permissions as the other non-Go connection. And on an on.

Comment: Start simple, create a test table, add a couple test rows, query the table in Beekeeper (without using a where clause to avoid additional complexity); now query the same table in the same way from Go. If you're not getting the same results, then the two connections are different. Use the most simple query you can think of, e.g `select id, name from table_test`.

Comment: I tried it and it works to make sure it is not some database fault i changed database and go client have same permission as it is able to run other queries like `INSERT` and `CREATE TABLE`, also it is a local database so there are no permission setup.